# Respuesta API REST muestra valor double con letra e de notacion cientifica

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

tengo un api rest en java 8 con spring-boot y mi servicio retorna un json donde me muestra mi valor Double con la letra E en su interior (notacion cientifica). Mi valor en la DB está almacenado sin letra E. Al recuperarlo ya lo guarda en mi property Double con la letra E. Como puedo hacer que la respuesta del API sea sin la E en el valor del double???. Les muestro mi clase de respuesta.

```
public class Empresa {
    private String nombre;
    private Double monto;
    // getters y setters aca

}
```

y la respuesta que veo es:

```
{
    "Empresa": {
        "nombre": "Empresa1",
        "monto": 4.23423443E8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré el inconveniente. Publico la respuesta por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo. El problema viene con que Double tiene menos precisión que BigDecimal y ahí es donde los Doubles que tienen valores muy grandes agregan la letra E. Lo que hice fue manejar desde que obtengo hasta que devuelvo siempre con BigDecimal que, aunque es mas lerdo, es mas seguro y con mayor precisión. Aquí les dejo un link donde se explica con un poco mas de detalle lo que yo estoy haciendo. Leer: [Por que usar BigDecimal (y no Double) para calculos aritmeticos financieros](https://www.javamexico.org/blogs/luxspes/por_que_usar_bigdecimal_y_no_double_para_calculos_aritmeticos_financieros)